# PostgreSQL: skip selecting row if found more than one row with similar column value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following selection:

```sql
SELECT
    posm.id AS org_scope_metric_id,
    cc.code AS control_code,
    ccp.code AS part_code,
    pop.id AS program_id
FROM public.org_scope_metric posm
JOIN public.org_metric pom ON pom.id = posm.metric_id
JOIN compliance.metric cm ON cm.id = pom.metric_id
JOIN compliance.control_part_metric ccpm ON ccpm.metric_id = cm.id
JOIN compliance.control_part ccp ON ccp.id = ccpm.part_id
JOIN compliance.control cc ON cc.id = ccp.control_id
JOIN compliance.program_framework cpf ON cpf.framework_id = cc.framework_id
JOIN public.org_program pop ON pop.program_id = cpf.program_id
WHERE posm.scope_id ='e6d11bfe-e5fc-11ee-8cda-238cdb93d281'
GROUP BY posm.id, cc.code, ccp.code, pop.id
```

that returns such result:
[image]

If there are **org_scope_metric_id**s with different **program_id** I need to skip them all from the selection.

Please help to resolve it!

Comment: could you please elaborate your question?

Comment: Please always include a [mre]. That is, ***both*** example source data ***and*** desired results for that example data. [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count the number of equal `org_scope_metric_id` occurrences and the number of distinct `program_id`-s in each group and then filter result rows with *both* numbers greater than 1.

```sql
with t as ( 
  select *, 
    count(*) over w cnt,
    array_agg(program_id) over w program_id_list
  from (<your query here>) t 
  window w as (partition by org_scope_metric_id)
)
select * from t 
where cnt > 1 and array_distinct_count(program_id_list) > 1;
```

You would need a helper function for that -

```sql
create or replace function array_distinct_count(arr anyarray)
returns integer language sql immutable as $$
 select count(distinct el) from unnest(arr) el;
$$;
```

Comment: I get `DISTINCT is not implemented for window functions` error :(

Comment: Oh, missed that. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `min` and `max` window functions

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        posm.id AS org_scope_metric_id,
        cc.code AS control_code,
        ccp.code AS part_code,
        pop.id AS program_id,
        MIN(pop.id) OVER (PARTITION BY posm.id) = MAX(pop.id) OVER (PARTITION BY posm.id) AS all_same_id
    FROM public.org_scope_metric posm
    JOIN public.org_metric pom ON pom.id = posm.metric_id
    JOIN compliance.metric cm ON cm.id = pom.metric_id
    JOIN compliance.control_part_metric ccpm ON ccpm.metric_id = cm.id
    JOIN compliance.control_part ccp ON ccp.id = ccpm.part_id
    JOIN compliance.control cc ON cc.id = ccp.control_id
    JOIN compliance.program_framework cpf ON cpf.framework_id = cc.framework_id
    JOIN public.org_program pop ON pop.program_id = cpf.program_id
    WHERE posm.scope_id ='e6d11bfe-e5fc-11ee-8cda-238cdb93d281'
    GROUP BY posm.id, cc.code, ccp.code, pop.id
) p
WHERE all_same_id;
```

Comment: Why not move the `MIN(pop.id) OVER (PARTITION BY posm.id) = MAX(pop.id) OVER (PARTITION BY posm.id)` to the WHERE-clause? and removing the need for a sub-query ?

Comment: Because you can't put window functions in the `WHERE`, only in a `QUALIFY` clause which Postgres does not support.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much guys. My final solution according to your suggestions is

```sql
SELECT
   org_scope_metric_id,
   program_scope_id,
   array_agg(program_scope_id) OVER (PARTITION BY org_scope_metric_id) AS metric_program_scopes
FROM (
  <long_selection_from_the_question>
) subquery
GROUP BY subquery.org_scope_metric_id, subquery.program_scope_id
```

So the main thing that I had to use `OVER (PARTITION BY)` to get necessary count.